XMLHttpRequest Get ID from Response
How do I get the ID from this response.
"{\"id\": \"9cf049a8-220a-4103-9f84-354276409390\", \"info\": {\"status\": \"Draft\", \"created_by\": \"email@.com\", \"location\": \"615 Bourbon St New Orleans\", \"order_type\": \"vbim\", \"first_delivered_at\": null, \"created_at\": 1725162699.505495, \"is_scan_order\": true, \"total_scanned_area\": 0.0, \"go2scan\": null, \"external_id\": \"R4ER93\", \"add_info\": \"Extra info\", \"style_template\": null, \"product\": {\"add_ons\": [], \"over_limits\": [], \"package_type\": \"plus\", \"purchasable_add_ons\": [], \"purchasable_package_types\": []}}, \"address\": {\"city\": \"New Orleans\", \"country\": \"United States\", \"full_address\": \"615 Bourbon St,New Orleans,Louisiana,United States\", \"latitude\": 29.958365, \"longitude\": -90.066198, \"number\": \"\", \"postalCode\": \"70130\", \"state\": \"Louisiana\", \"street\": \"615 Bourbon St\", \"suite\": \"\"}, \"delivery_assets\": {\"gla_package\": null, \"listing_floorplans\": null, \"home_report\": null, \"floorplans_3d\": null, \"video_3d\": null, \"cad_files\": null, \"property_data\": null, \"snapshot\": null}}"

Here is my Javascript
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://app.cubi.casa/api/integrate/v3/orders/draft');

request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('api-key', 'KEY');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (this.readyState === 4) {
console.log('Status:', this.status);
console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
}
};

var body = {
'street': '615 Bourbon St',
'suite': '',
'city': 'New Orleans',
'state': 'Louisiana',
'country': 'United States',
'postalCode': '70130',
'info': 'Extra info',
'latitude': 29.958365,
'longitude': -90.066198,
'external_id': 'R4ER93',
'owner_email': 'Email.com',
'package_type': 'plus'
};

request.send(JSON.stringify(body));


You can use request.onload method to handle the response, this onload will be called once the response is received from server.

@YashMaheshwari The readystate 4 can be used. OP wants the ID but is not parsing the responseText

You need to parse: console.log('id:', JSON.parse(this.responseText).id); or use fetch: fetch('https://app.cubi.casa/api/integrate/v3/orders/draft', {  method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': 'KEY' },  body: JSON.stringify(body) }) .then(response => response.json()) .then(object => console.log(object.id)).catch(error => console.error(error));
